# DOCKER + NGINX + PHP-FPM не работает (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, docker, php-fpm

Прошу помочь. Во все этих настройках не специалист. Всю голову уже сломал.

`docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    networks:
      - mynet

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    links:
      - php-fpm
    ports:
      - "8800:80"
      - "4433:443"
    volumes:
      - .:/home/user/project
      - ./docker/nginx/sites-available:/etc/nginx/sites-available
      - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    networks:
      - mynet

  php-fpm:
    image: php:7.4-fpm-alpine
    build: ./docker/php-fpm
    volumes:
      - .:/home/user/project
    links:
      - db
    networks:
      - mynet

  db:
    image: mysql:5
    volumes:
      - ./docker/db:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - '3308:3306'
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mybase
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true
    networks:
      - mynet

networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine
RUN ls
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN apk add --no-cache git
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath
RUN apk add --update --no-cache gmp gmp-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install gmp
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

`nginx.conf`

```
worker_processes 1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*.conf;
}
```

`default.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    charset utf-8;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/ch.local.error.log warn;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/ch.local.access.log;

    root /home/user/project/public;
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    location / {
            index index.php;
            if (!-e $request_filename){
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php last;
            }
        }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files      $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_pass   php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Сервер - Ubuntu 20 + Git + Docker. Больше ничего не стоит.

`docker-compose up` запускает все контейнеры. Все контейнеры рабочие. Nginx и PHP работают. В логах ничего. Но в браузере - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED по любому адресу и порту. Не видит, похоже. Только почему?

Comment: а по какому адресу вы пытаетесь зайти, точно 8800 порт? и монтируте вы папку `- .:/home/user/celeri-health` а в `root` указываете `/home/user/project/public;` это точно так?

Comment: Пытаюсь зайти по айпи сервера.И с указание порта и без. Это ошибка. Прсто я название проекта на project не везде поменял.

Comment: Да, пожалуй, я тупой. Спасибо, помогли. 8080 порт закрыт был. А с него идет редирект на 80.